# How to convert Bitmapdata to Base64 format?

Tags: haxe, openfl

Is there any example which helps in generating Base64 based image from Bitmapdata?
I know I have to use encode in bitmapdata, but I am not sure how to use it?

It takes (rect : flash.geom.Rectangle, compressor : flash.utils.Object, ?byteArray : flash.utils.ByteArray) : flash.utils.ByteArray;

How to fill compressor incase I want to compress using jpeg?

Also, what's the input of byteArray ?
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example in the [AS3 doc of BitmapData.html#encode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#encode%28%29):

```
// Compress a BitmapData object as a JPEG file.
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640,480,false,0x00FF00);
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0,0,640,480), new flash.display.JPEGEncoderOptions(), byteArray);
```

To generate a Base64 String, you can use [`haxe.crypto.Base64`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/crypto/Base64.hx) (added after 3.0.1).
In OpenFL, `ByteArray` extends `Bytes`. So you may simply feed it to `Base64.encode`.

Comment: Thank you, as for AS3, byteArray is passed to encode method, by why in openFL encode returns byteArray? isn't it sent by reference already?

Comment: Oh, indeed, looking at the [method signature of BitmapData.html#encode()](https://github.com/openfl/openfl-native/blob/master/flash/display/BitmapData.hx#L163) in OpenFL, seems like it always create the ByteArray for you, instead of letting you to pass a byteArray for it to write to. Definitely it _should_ follow AS3's signature. Feel free to report the issue.

Comment: Well... Also, the format param in OpenFL accepts only `"png"` or `"jpg"`, but not `JPEGEncoderOptions` or anything...

Comment: I saw that it accepts flash.utils.Object, that was the source of confusion to me, any way I've used the open source library of polygonal-gl, I think it will work for me easily